# Couldnot upload images to AWS S3 bucket in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phantomjs

I am having a scenario where the photos I am uploading has to store in a AWS S3 buckets and call the images in through email but after the Rails and corresponding gems upgradation I could not store the images in S3. I upgraded my aws-s3 version from 0.6.1 to 0.6.3, aws-sdk from 1.3.5 to 1.3.9, right_aws from 3.0.0 to 3.0.5 and finally Rails version from 3.2.1 to 4.2.6.

I have tested by putting puts commands, it is going to all the methods but I doubt whether there is any syntax change in upload method at @type (Here @type is the 2 bucket names photo_screenshots and indicator_screenshots).
Please help me.

This is my lib/screenshot.rb:

```
    class Screenshot
      attr_reader :user_id, :report_id, :type

      def initialize(user_id, report_id, type)
          @user_id, @report_id, @type = user_id, report_id, type
          capture
          resize(500, 686) if @type == 'report_screenshots'
          upload
          delete_local_copy
      end

      def capture
        if Rails.env.production?
          phantom    = Rails.root.join('vendor/javascripts/phantomjs_linux/bin/phantomjs')
          url        = Rails.application.config.custom.domain_url + "users/#{@user_id}/reports/#{@report_id}"
        end
        js           = Rails.root.join("vendor/javascripts/#{@type}.js")
        image        = Rails.root.join("public/#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png")

        `/bin/bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 #{phantom} #{js} #{url} #{image}"`
      end

      def resize(width, height)
        path = "public/#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png"
        img = Magick::Image::read(path).first
        #img.thumbnail!(width, height)
        img.change_geometry("#{width}x#{height}") do |cols, rows, img|
          img.thumbnail!(cols, rows)
        end
        img.write(path)
      end

      def upload
        file_name = Rails.root.join("public/#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png")
        s3config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 's3.yml'))[Rails.env]
        s3 = RightAws::S3.new(s3config["access_key_id"], s3config["secret_access_key"])
        @type == 'report_screenshots' ? s3.bucket("my_project.#{Rails.env}", true).put("#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' }) : s3.bucket("my_project.#{Rails.env}", true).put("indicator_screenshots/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' })
        report = Report.find(@report_id)
        @type == 'report_screenshots' ? report.update_attribute(:report_screenshot_at, Time.now) : report.update_attribute(:indicator_screenshot_at, Time.now)
      end

      def delete_local_copy
        file_name = Rails.root.join("public/#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png")
        File.delete(file_name)
      end

      def self.delete_s3_copy(report_id, type)
        s3config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 's3.yml'))[Rails.env]
        s3 = RightAws::S3.new(s3config["access_key_id"], s3config["secret_access_key"])
        s3.bucket("my_project.#{Rails.env}").key("#{type}/#{report_id}.png").delete
      end


end
```

Whenever I click on send an email, this is what happens:

controller:

```
  def send_test_email
    if @report.photos.empty?
      Rails.env.development? ? Screenshot.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.indicator_screenshot_bucket) : Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.indicator_screenshot_bucket)
    else
      Rails.env.development? ? Screenshot.new(@user.id, @report.id, "photo_screenshots") : Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, "photo_screenshots")
    end
    ReportMailer.delay.test_report_email(@user, @report)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :notice => 'Test email was successfully sent!' } }
    end
  end
```

This is RAILS_ENV=production log:

> New RightAws::S3Interface using shared connections mode Opening new
>   HTTPS connection to my_project.production.s3.amazonaws.com:443 Opening
>   new HTTPS connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 2016-09-26T10:48:46+0000:
>   [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-172-31-24-139 pid:8769)] Job
>   Screenshot.new (id=528) FAILED (16 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT:
>   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /var/www/html/project/my_project/public/photo_screenshots/50031.png
>   2016-09-26T10:48:46+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-172-31-24-139
>   pid:8769)] Job Screenshot.new (id=529) RUNNING
>   2016-09-26T10:48:46+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-172-31-24-139
>   pid:8769)] Job Screenshot.new (id=529) FAILED (16 prior attempts) with
>   Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open file
>   `public/report_screenshots/50031.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3733
>   2016-09-26T10:48:46+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-172-31-24-139
>   pid:8769)] 2 jobs processed at 1.6978 j/s, 2 failed

This is AWS production log:

> New RightAws::S3Interface using shared connections mode
>   2016-09-26T16:00:30+0530: [Worker(host:OSI-L-0397 pid:7117)] Job
>   Screenshot.new (id=50) FAILED (6 prior attempts) with Errno::ENOENT:
>   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /home/abcuser/Desktop/project/my_project/public/photo_screenshots/10016.png
>   2016-09-26T16:00:30+0530: [Worker(host:OSI-L-0397 pid:7117)] Job
>   Screenshot.new (id=51) RUNNING 2016-09-26T16:00:30+0530:
>   [Worker(host:OSI-L-0397 pid:7117)] Job Screenshot.new (id=51) FAILED
>   (6 prior attempts) with Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open file
>   `public/report_screenshots/10016.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3667
>   2016-09-26T16:00:30+0530: [Worker(host:OSI-L-0397 pid:7117)] 2 jobs
>   processed at 0.2725 j/s, 2 failed

Comment: This looks like the hardest way to accomplish file uploads lol.  Download the 'paperclip gem' to use with S3 and remove 95% of this code.

Comment: There are lot of dependencies on it, so I couldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading in a simpler approach.

Uploading images to a fixed bucket with different folders for each object or application.The s3 keeps a limitation on the number of buckets creattion whereas there is no
              limitation for content inside a bucket.

This code will upload image for a user to s3 using aws-sdk gem. The bucket and the image uploaded are made public 
              so that the images uploaded are directly accessible. The input it takes is the image complete path 
              where it is present, folder in which it should be uploaded and user_id for whom it should 
              be uploaded.

```
            def save_screenshot_to_s3(image_location, folder_name,user_id)
              service = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                    :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
              bucket_name = "app-images"
              if(service.buckets.include?(bucket_name))
                bucket = service.buckets[bucket_name]
              else
                bucket = service.buckets.create(bucket_name)
              end
              bucket.acl = :public_read
              key = folder_name.to_s + "/" + File.basename(image_location)
              s3_file = service.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => image_location)
              s3_file.acl = :public_read
              user = User.where(id: user_id).first
              user.image = s3_file.public_url.to_s
              user.save
            end
```

**for handling the screenshot part**, in your capture method you have use done something like this.

```
  `/bin/bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 #{phantom} #{js} #{url} #{image}"`
```

Is the **/bin/bash** thing really required, change it to below code and it should work.

```
      `DISPLAY=:0 "#{phantom}" "#{js}" "#{url}" "#{image}"`
```

let it be if it breaks something else.
Since you are aware of the final image location which is **image**. Pass this directly to save_screenshot_to_s3 and you should be able to save it. This will save the image path to user too if you pass your user_id as specified in method

Comment: There are lot of dependencies on it, so I couldn't change. Can you please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: @sachingod i see you are using phantom, are you trying to take a screenshot and then save. If yes i'll update my ans

Comment: exactly. I am trying to take a screenshot and save.

Comment: Where are the error logs in the updated version of qsn

Comment: added. please check

Comment: As per the logs, the images are not available. first you try to hard code all the images and make them available. Do a dry run and see if it works before you debug the aws upload code.

Comment: I have checked and found that the problem is at the screenshot level, it is not capturing screenshot to upload.

Comment: Also haven't upgraded phantomjs as the gem is not used.